# How to write a greasemonkey script to remove a confim dialog?

Tags: greasemonkey

I wanted to write a very simple greasemonkey script because I hate the "are you sure?" javascript confirmation on a site I use a lot. I'm just going to use it for personal use, not going to publish it or anything. After some Googling I found http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow explaining what it seems that I want to do.

The source code for the page I want is like this

```
var message = "Are you sure?";
function confirmIt(message) {
    var result = confirm(message);
    return result;
}
```

I want to replace confirmIt(message) with just return true;

So I made a script

```
var oldFunction = unsafeWindow.confirmIt(message);
    unsafeWindow.confirmIt(message) = function() {
    return true;
};
```

I get the error "message is not defined."

I'm not sure if I'm going about this right (I'm thinking not), but I'd appreciate some guidance from someone with more experience in Greasemonkey, about how to replace a Javascript function on a page.

Comment: If you post the webpage, I could probably tell you. It it likely the popup you see is just a overlaying div - hide the div each time the page is loaded using greasymonkey and you have an easier job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think of unsafeWindow.confirmIt as a variable in addition to a function (which it is).  So, the way to do what you're attempting in your code would be:

```
var oldFunction = unsafeWindow.confirmIt;

unsafeWindow.confirmIt = function(message) {
    return true;
};
```

Try that.

Comment: Worked! Thank you. Curious though, I don't care about accessing the variable message in my function, but what if I did want to, how would I do that if I don't seem to have access to the parameters?

Comment: You do have access to the parameters.  Your function is defined as taking a parameter which it refers to as "message".  You could say 
     unsafeWindow.confirmIt = function(message) {alert(message); return true;};
 and it would work exactly as you'd expect.